# Unity - Rotate and Position a GameObject towards it's target GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two GameObjects: source and target, where each GameObject have attached 4 connectors.

For example: when I drag the **front** connector (white) of source GameObject on the **right** connector (green) of target GameObject, then the source GameObject should be rotated and positioned on target position and rotation)

[image]

I have already tried `transform.LookAt` and `Quaternion.LookRotation` without any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the right part of the image is the result I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: First, get an angle between the white connector and the green connector. Then simply rotate the game object and of course, calculate the position.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get the angle and then calculate the position?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) function to calculate the angle between 2 points and use the result to rotate the whole gameobject.

You can rotate an object with multiple ways. One way is to use a coroutine like this:

```
var calulatedAngle = Vector3.Angle(whitePointPosition,greenPointPosition);
StartCoroutine(RotateObject(calculatedAngle))

IEnumerator RotateObject(float targetAngle)
{
    isRotating = true;
    float currentAngle = 0f;

    while (currentAngle < targetAngle)
    {
        float rotationAmount = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAmount);
        currentAngle += rotationAmount;
        yield return null;
    }
    isRotating = false;
}
```

- **rotationSpeed** determines how fast your object will rotate

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Also transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAmount) should be whitePointPosition.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAmount) but still it doesn't work.